# Return ActiveRecord::Relation using raw SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below are few rows of `indicator_values` database table with records of countries and indicators for repeated years:

[image]

I would like to get the `value` that corresponds to the most recent year for each country into an array:

```
[{"name"=>"Water", "data"=>[86.35, 88.34]},                #indicator2
 {"name"=>"Electricity", "data"=>[68.62, 94.47]}, ....]    #indicator1
```

I can get the recent years data for each country and indicator using a query and then apply `.where()` and `.pluck()` active record queries on the object returned by the SQL query.

```
[2,3,4].map { |i| 
        sql = "SELECT a.country_id,  a.indicator_id, a.value, a.year
              FROM indicator_values a
              INNER JOIN (
                SELECT country_id, indicator_id, MAX(year) AS year
                FROM indicator_values
                GROUP BY country_id, indicator_id
              ) b ON a.country_id = b.country_id AND a.year = b.year and a.indicator_id = b.indicator_id
              ORDER BY country_id, indicator_id;"

        recent_years_data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
        my_array = { "name" => Indicator.find(i).name, "data" => recent_years_data.where('indicator_id = (?) and country_id IN (?)', i, selected_countries).pluck(:value) } }
```

The result of the query is not an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object and therefore it cannot work with `.where()` and `.pluck()`. I seek a way to get an `ActiveRecord::Relation` or a different workaround to create the desired array. Similar posts advice using Active Record Query but I could not get to how to chain such a long query as an Active Record Query instead of raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I got a different approach that works and which does not involve using joins.

```
IndicatorValue.
    select('DISTINCT ON (cvs.country_id, cvs.indicator_id), cvs.*').
    order('cvs.country_id, cvs.indicator_id, cvs.year DESC')
```

`cvs` stands for `indicator_values`
The result is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`